# D3D D2D Interop on Windows 7

Tags: c++-cli, directx-11, direct2d, directx-10, directwrite

I'm trying to use DWrite to draw text in my dx11 app but I'm having lot of problems, I shared resources beetween D3D10 Device and D3D11 Device because dx10 is capable to connect D3D with D2D, that's the code of my GraphicsDevice:

```
// File: GraphicsDevice.h

#pragma once

#ifndef _GRAPHICSDEVICE_H_
#define _GRAPHICSDEVICE_H_

#ifndef _DEFINES_H_
#include "Defines.h"
#endif
#ifndef _COLOR_H_
#include "Color.h"
#endif
#ifndef _UTILITIES_H_
#include "Utilities.h"
#endif
#ifndef _DWRITE_H_
#include "DWrite.h"
#endif

// Forward declaration
namespace BSGameFramework { ref class Game; }

using namespace BSGameFramework;
using namespace System;

namespace BSGameFramework
{
namespace Graphics
{
    public ref class GraphicsDevice
    {
        public:

            /// <summary>GraphicsDevice constructor.</summary>
            /// <param name="game">The game wich the device has to work.</param>
            GraphicsDevice(Game^ game);
            virtual ~GraphicsDevice();

            /// <summary>Clear the screen.</summary>
            /// <param name="color">The color that the screen background will assume after clearing.</param>
            void Clear(Color color);
            /// <summary>Render on the screen.</summary>
            void Render();
            /// <summary>Set the full screen state.</summary>
            void FullScreen(bool isFullScreen);

            property Color BlendFactor
            {
                Color get()
                {
                    return blendFactor_;
                }

                void set(Color blendFactor_)
                {
                    blendFactor_ = BlendFactor;
                }
            }

            property D3D_DRIVER_TYPE DriverType
            {
                D3D_DRIVER_TYPE get()
                {
                    return driverType_;
                }
            }

            property D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevel
            {
                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL get()
                {
                    return featureLevel_;
                }
            }

            property ID3D11Device* D3DDevice
            {
                ID3D11Device* get()
                {
                    return d3dDevice_;
                }
            }

            property ID3D11DeviceContext* D3DContext
            {
                ID3D11DeviceContext* get()
                {
                    return d3dContext_;
                }
            }

            property ID3D10Device1* D3DDevice10_1
            {
                ID3D10Device1* get()
                {
                    return d3dDevice10_1_;
                }
            }

            property ID2D1Factory* D2DFactory
            {
                ID2D1Factory* get()
                {
                    return d2dFactory_;
                }
            }

            property ID2D1RenderTarget* D2DRenderTarget
            {
                ID2D1RenderTarget* get()
                {
                    return d2dRenderTarget_;
                }
            }

            property ID2D1SolidColorBrush* D2DSolidColorBrush
            {
                ID2D1SolidColorBrush* get()
                {
                    return d2dSolidColorBrush_;
                }
            }

            property IDWriteFactory* DWriteFactory
            {
                IDWriteFactory* get()
                {
                    return dWriteFactory_;
                }
            }

            property int WindowWidth
            {
                int get()
                {
                    return GetWindowWidth();
                }
            }

            property int WindowHeight
            {
                int get()
                {
                    return GetWindowHeight();
                }
            }

            property HWND Window
            {
                HWND get()
                {
                    return GetWindow(); 
                }
            }

            property int SafeTitleArea
            {
                int get()
                {
                    return safeTitleArea_;
                }

                void set(int safeTitleArea)
                {
                    safeTitleArea_ = safeTitleArea;
                }
            }

        private:

            void CreateD3D11Resources();
            void CreateD3D10Resources(ID3D11Texture2D* d3d11Texture);
            void CreateD2D1Resources(ID3D10Texture2D* d3d10Texture);

            Game^ game_;
            Color blendFactor_;
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverType_;
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel_;
            int safeTitleArea_;

            int GetWindowWidth();
            int GetWindowHeight();
            HWND GetWindow();

            // Direct3D 11

            ID3D11Device* d3dDevice_;
            ID3D11DeviceContext* d3dContext_;

            // Direct3D 10

            ID3D10Device1* d3dDevice10_1_;

            // Direct2D

            ID2D1Factory* d2dFactory_;
            ID2D1RenderTarget* d2dRenderTarget_;
            ID2D1SolidColorBrush* d2dSolidColorBrush_;

            // DirectWrite

            IDWriteFactory* dWriteFactory_;

            IDXGISwapChain* swapChain_;
            ID3D11RenderTargetView* backBufferTarget_;
    };
}
}

#endif
```

---

```
// FILE: GraphicsDevice.cpp

#include "GraphicsDevice.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "GraphicsDeviceNativeWrapper.h"

using namespace BSGameFramework::Graphics;
using namespace BSGameFramework;

inline GraphicsDevice::GraphicsDevice(Game^ game) : driverType_( D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL ),     featureLevel_( D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 ),
                            d3dDevice_( 0 ), d3dContext_( 0 ), swapChain_( 0 ), backBufferTarget_( 0 )
{
game_ = game;
BlendFactor = Color::White;

CreateD3D11Resources();
}

inline GraphicsDevice::~GraphicsDevice()
{
if (backBufferTarget_)
{
    backBufferTarget_->Release();
}

if (swapChain_)
{
    swapChain_->Release();
}

if (d3dContext_)
{
    d3dContext_->Release();
}

if (d3dDevice_)
{
    d3dDevice_->Release();
}

backBufferTarget_ = 0;
swapChain_ = 0;
d3dContext_ = 0;
d3dDevice_ = 0;
}

inline void GraphicsDevice::Clear(Color color)
{
if (d3dContext_ == 0)
{
    return;
}

float clearColor[4];
Vec4 convertedColor = Utilities::ColorToVec4(color);
clearColor[0] = convertedColor.values[0];
clearColor[1] = convertedColor.values[1];
clearColor[2] = convertedColor.values[2];
clearColor[3] = convertedColor.values[3];

d3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView(backBufferTarget_, clearColor);
}

inline void GraphicsDevice::Render()
{
swapChain_->Present(0, 0);
}

inline void GraphicsDevice::FullScreen(bool isFullScreen)
{
swapChain_->SetFullscreenState(isFullScreen, NULL);
}

inline int GraphicsDevice::GetWindowWidth()
{
return game_->WindowWidth;
}

inline int GraphicsDevice::GetWindowHeight()
{
return game_->WindowHeight;
}

inline HWND GraphicsDevice::GetWindow()
{
return game_->Window;
}

#pragma region CreateD3D11Resources

inline void GraphicsDevice::CreateD3D11Resources()
{
HRESULT result;

RECT dimensions;
GetClientRect(Window, &dimensions);

unsigned int width = dimensions.right - dimensions.left;
unsigned int height = dimensions.bottom - dimensions.top;

D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
{
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_SOFTWARE
};

unsigned int totalDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE(driverTypes);

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
};

unsigned int totalFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = game_->Window;
swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

unsigned int creationFlags = 0;

#ifdef _DEBUG
creationFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

unsigned int driver = 0;

pin_ptr<IDXGISwapChain*> swapChainPointer;
swapChainPointer = &swapChain_;

pin_ptr<ID3D11Device*> d3dDevicePointer;
d3dDevicePointer = &d3dDevice_;

pin_ptr<D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL> featureLevelPointer;
featureLevelPointer = &featureLevel_;

pin_ptr<ID3D11DeviceContext*> d3dContextPointer;
d3dContextPointer = &d3dContext_;

for (driver = 0; driver < totalDriverTypes; ++driver)
{
    result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(0, driverTypes[driver], 0, creationFlags, featureLevels, totalFeatureLevels,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, swapChainPointer,
        d3dDevicePointer, featureLevelPointer, d3dContextPointer);

    if (SUCCEEDED(result))
    {
        driverType_ = driverTypes[driver];
        break;
    }
}

if (FAILED(result))
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Failed to create the Direct3D device!");
    return;
}

ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferTexture;

result = swapChain_->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferTexture);

if (FAILED(result))
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Failed to get the swap chain back buffer!");
    return;
}

pin_ptr<ID3D11RenderTargetView*> backBufferTargetPointer;
backBufferTargetPointer = &backBufferTarget_;

result = d3dDevice_->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferTexture, 0, backBufferTargetPointer);

if (FAILED(result))
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Failed to create the render target view!");
    return;
}

d3dContext_->OMSetRenderTargets(1, backBufferTargetPointer, 0);

D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
viewport.Width = static_cast<float>(width);
viewport.Height = static_cast<float>(height);
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

d3dContext_->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

CreateD3D10Resources(backBufferTexture);
}

#pragma endregion

#pragma region CreateD3D10Resources

inline void GraphicsDevice::CreateD3D10Resources(ID3D11Texture2D* d3d11Texture)
{
//Load D3D10.DLL
HMODULE d3d10_1 = LoadLibrary("D3D10_1.dll");

// Get adapter of the current D3D11 device. Our D3D10 will run on the same adapter.
IDXGIDevice* dxgiDevice;
IDXGIAdapter* dxgiAdapter;

d3dDevice_->QueryInterface<IDXGIDevice>(&dxgiDevice);
dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&dxgiAdapter);
SafeRelease<IDXGIDevice>(&dxgiDevice);

//Get address of the function D3D10CreateDevice1 dynamically.
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI* FN_D3D10CreateDevice1)(
       IDXGIAdapter *pAdapter, D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE DriverType, HMODULE Software,
       UINT Flags, D3D10_FEATURE_LEVEL1 HardwareLevel, UINT SDKVersion, ID3D10Device1 **ppDevice );

FN_D3D10CreateDevice1 fnCreate = (FN_D3D10CreateDevice1)GetProcAddress(d3d10_1, "D3D10CreateDevice1");

//Call D3D10CreateDevice1 dynamically.
pin_ptr<ID3D10Device1*> d3dDevice10_1Ptr = &d3dDevice10_1_;

fnCreate(dxgiAdapter, D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, D3D10_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1, D3D10_1_SDK_VERSION, d3dDevice10_1Ptr);

//Create a D3D10.1 render target texture and share it with our D3D11.
D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC tDesc;
tDesc.Width = game_->WindowWidth;
tDesc.Height = game_->WindowHeight;
tDesc.MipLevels = 1;
tDesc.ArraySize = 1;
tDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
tDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
tDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
tDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
//EVEN IF YOU WON'T USE AS SHADER RESOURCE, SET THIS BIND FLAGS:
tDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D10_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
tDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
tDesc.MiscFlags = D3D10_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;

//Create the RT texture on D3D10
ID3D10Texture2D* texture;
d3dDevice10_1_->CreateTexture2D(&tDesc, NULL, &texture);

//Get DXGI Resource and retrieve the sharing handle.
IDXGISurface* dxgiSurface;
IDXGIResource* dxgiResource;
HANDLE shareHandle;

texture->QueryInterface<IDXGISurface>(&dxgiSurface);
dxgiSurface->QueryInterface<IDXGIResource>(&dxgiResource);
dxgiResource->GetSharedHandle(&shareHandle);
SafeRelease(&dxgiResource);
SafeRelease(&dxgiSurface);

//Call D3D 11 to open shared resource.
ID3D11Resource* d3d11Resource;

d3dDevice_->OpenSharedResource(shareHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), (void**)&d3d11Resource);
d3d11Resource->QueryInterface<ID3D11Texture2D>(&d3d11Texture);
SafeRelease(&d3d11Resource);

if (d3d11Texture)
{
    d3d11Texture->Release();
}

CreateD2D1Resources(texture);
}

#pragma endregion

#pragma region CreateD2D1Resources

inline void GraphicsDevice::CreateD2D1Resources(ID3D10Texture2D* d3d10Texture)
{
pin_ptr<ID2D1Factory*> d2dFactoryPtr = &d2dFactory_;
pin_ptr<IDWriteFactory*> dWriteFactoryPtr = &dWriteFactory_;
//pin_ptr<ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*> d2dRenderTargetPtr = &d2dRenderTarget_;
//pin_ptr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush*> D2DSolidColorBrushPtr = &d2dSolidColorBrush_;

GraphicsDeviceNativeWrapper::CreateFactories(Window, d2dFactoryPtr, dWriteFactoryPtr);

//Get DXGI Surface from the created render target.
IDXGISurface1* pRT10;
d3d10Texture->QueryInterface<IDXGISurface1>(&pRT10);

FLOAT dpiX;
FLOAT dpiY;
d2dFactory_->GetDesktopDpi(&dpiX, &dpiY);

// Create a DC render target.
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
static_cast<float>(dpiX),
static_cast<float>(dpiY)
);

// Create a Direct2D render target.
// Assuming m_pD2DFactory was previously created with:
//D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, __uuidof(ID2D1Factory), NULL,
//   (void**)(&m_pD2DFactory));
pin_ptr<ID2D1RenderTarget*> renderTargetPtr = &d2dRenderTarget_;

d2dFactory_->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(pRT10, (const D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES *)&props, renderTargetPtr);

pin_ptr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush*> solidColorBrushPtr = &d2dSolidColorBrush_;
d2dRenderTarget_->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White), solidColorBrushPtr);
}

#pragma endregion
```

---

```
// File GraphicsDeviceNativeWrapper.h

#pragma once

#ifndef _GRAPHICSDEVICENATIVEWRAPPER_H_
#define _GRAPHICSDEVICENATIVEWRAPPER_H_

#ifndef _DWRITE_H_
#include "DWrite.h"
#endif

#pragma managed(push, false)

namespace BSGameFramework
{
namespace Graphics
{
    class GraphicsDeviceNativeWrapper abstract sealed
    {
        public:

            static void CreateFactories(HWND window, ID2D1Factory** d2dFactory, IDWriteFactory** dWriteFactory/*,ID2D1RenderTarget** d2dRenderTarget, ID2D1SolidColorBrush** d2dSolidColorBrush*/)
            {
                HRESULT result;

                result = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,__uuidof(ID2D1Factory), NULL, (void**)d2dFactory);

                if (SUCCEEDED(result))
                {
                    result = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(IDWriteFactory), reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(dWriteFactory));
                }

                RECT rc;
                GetClientRect(window, &rc);

                D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

            }

            static void CreateTextFormat(const wchar_t* font, IDWriteFactory* factory, IDWriteTextFormat** format)
            {
                factory->CreateTextFormat(font, NULL, DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_REGULAR, DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL, DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL, 72.0f, L"en-us", format);

                (*format)->SetTextAlignment(DWRITE_TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                (*format)->SetParagraphAlignment(DWRITE_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            }
    };
}
}

#pragma managed(pop)

#endif
```

---

And this is my SpriteBatch:

```
// File: SpriteBatch.h

#pragma once

#ifndef _SPRITEBATCH_H_
#define _SPRITEBATCH_H_

#ifndef _DEFINES_H_
#include "Defines.h"
#endif
#ifndef _GRAPHICRESOURCE_H_
#include "GraphicResource.h"
#endif
#ifndef _TEXTURE2D_H_
#include "Texture2D.h"
#endif
#ifndef _GRAPHICSDEVICE_H_
#include "GraphicsDevice.h"
#endif
#ifndef _SPRITESORTMODE_H_
#include "SpriteSortMode.h"
#endif
#ifndef _BLENDSTATE_H_
#include "BlendState.h"
#endif
#ifndef _NATIVESPRITEBATCH_H_
#include "NativeSpritebatch.h"
#endif
#ifndef _SPRITEEFFECT_H_
#include "SpriteEffect.h"
#endif
#ifndef _IDRAWABLECOMPONENT_H_
#include "IDrawableComponent.h"
#endif
#ifndef _SPRITEFONT_H_
#include "SpriteFont.h"
#endif

using namespace BSGameFramework::GameBase;

namespace BSGameFramework
{
namespace Graphics
{
    public ref class SpriteBatch : GraphicResource
    {
        public:

            SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice^ graphicsDevice);
            ~SpriteBatch();

            void Begin();
            void Begin(SpriteSortMode sortMode, BlendState^ blendState);
            void Draw(IDrawableComponent^ component);
            void DrawString(SpriteFont^ font, System::String^ text, Vector2 position);
            void End();

        private:

            bool CompileD3DShader(char* filePath, char* entry, char* shaderModel, ID3DBlob** buffer);
            void SortByDepth();

            SpriteSortMode sortMode_;
            BlendState ^blendState_;
            System::Collections::Generic::List<IDrawableComponent^>^ componentList_;
            bool beginInvoked_;

            ID3D11VertexShader* solidColorVS_;
            ID3D11PixelShader* solidColorPS_;

            ID3D11InputLayout* inputLayout_;
            ID3D11Buffer* vertexBuffer_;

            ID3D11BlendState* alphaBlendState_;

            NativeSpritebatch* spriteBatch;
    };
}
}

#endif
```

---

```
// File: SpriteBatch.cpp

#include "SpriteBatch.h"
#ifndef _SPRITEBATCHBEGINENDEXCEPTION_H_
#include "SpriteBatchBeginEndException.h"
#endif

using namespace BSGameFramework::Graphics;
using namespace BSGameFramework::Exception;

inline SpriteBatch::SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice^ graphicsDevice) : alphaBlendState_( 0 )
{
graphicDevice_ = graphicsDevice;
sortMode_ = SpriteSortMode::Deferred;
blendState_ = BlendState::AlphaBlend;

// ID3DBlob contiene un puntatore ad un dato di lunghezza qualsiasi, GetBufferPointer restituisce il puntatore e GetBufferSize la grandezza
ID3DBlob* vsBuffer = 0;
// Compila lo shader e salva il risultato nel buffer
bool compileResult = CompileD3DShader("TextureMap.fx", "VS_Main", "vs_4_0", &vsBuffer);

if (compileResult == false)
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Error compiling the vertex shader!");
    return;
}

HRESULT d3dResult;

pin_ptr<ID3D11VertexShader*> solidColorVSPointer;
solidColorVSPointer = &solidColorVS_;
// Crea il vertex shader e lo salva in solidColorVS_ di tipo ID3D11VertexShader*
d3dResult = Device->D3DDevice->CreateVertexShader(vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), 0, solidColorVSPointer);

if (FAILED(d3dResult))
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Error creating the vertex shader!");

    if (vsBuffer)
    {
        vsBuffer->Release();
    }

    return;
}

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC solidColorLayout[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};

unsigned int totalLayoutElements = ARRAYSIZE(solidColorLayout);

pin_ptr<ID3D11InputLayout*> inputLayoutPointer;
inputLayoutPointer = &inputLayout_;
// Crea l'input layout e lo salva in inputLayout di tipo ID3D11InputLayout*
d3dResult = Device->D3DDevice->CreateInputLayout(solidColorLayout, totalLayoutElements, vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), inputLayoutPointer);

vsBuffer->Release();

if (FAILED(d3dResult))
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Error creating the input layout!");
    return;
}

ID3DBlob* psBuffer = 0;
// Compila il pixel shader e salva il risultato in psBuffer
compileResult = CompileD3DShader("TextureMap.fx", "PS_Main", "ps_4_0", &psBuffer);

if (compileResult == false)
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Error compiling pixel shader!");
    return;
}

pin_ptr<ID3D11PixelShader*> solidColorPSPointer;
solidColorPSPointer = &solidColorPS_;
// Crea il pixel shader e lo salva in solidColorPS_ di tipo ID3D11PixelShader*
d3dResult = Device->D3DDevice->CreatePixelShader(psBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), psBuffer->GetBufferSize(), 0, solidColorPSPointer);;

psBuffer->Release();

if (FAILED(d3dResult))
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Error creating pixel shader!");
    return;
}

spriteBatch = new NativeSpritebatch(Device->D3DDevice);

// Spostare nel Begin successivamente
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendDesc;
ZeroMemory(&blendDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC));
blendDesc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
blendDesc.IndependentBlendEnable = FALSE;        
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = TRUE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_DEST_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

float blendFactor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

pin_ptr<ID3D11BlendState*> alphaBlendStatePointer;
alphaBlendStatePointer = &alphaBlendState_;

Device->D3DDevice->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, alphaBlendStatePointer);
Device->D3DContext->OMSetBlendState(alphaBlendState_, blendFactor, 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

inline SpriteBatch::~SpriteBatch()
{
}

inline void SpriteBatch::Begin()
{
if (beginInvoked_)
{
    throw gcnew SpriteBatchBeginEndException("Beetween two SpriteBatch begin methods you must call SpriteBacth End method!");
}

beginInvoked_ = true;

Device->D2DRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
Device->D2DRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::IdentityMatrix());

if (componentList_ == nullptr)
{
    componentList_ = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<IDrawableComponent^>();
}
}

inline void SpriteBatch::Begin(SpriteSortMode sortMode, BlendState^ blendState)
{
Begin();

sortMode_ = sortMode;
}

inline void SpriteBatch::Draw(IDrawableComponent^ component)
{
if (component == nullptr)
{
    throw gcnew ArgumentNullException("Component argument is null, please ensure to initialize all components correctly!");
}
else
{
    componentList_->Add(component);
}
}

inline void SpriteBatch::DrawString(SpriteFont^ font, System::String^ text, Vector2 position)
{
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(Device->Window, &rc);

// Create a D2D rect that is the same size as the window.

D2D1_RECT_F layoutRect = D2D1::RectF(
    static_cast<FLOAT>(rc.left) / font->DpiScaleX,
    static_cast<FLOAT>(rc.top) / font->DpiScaleY,
    static_cast<FLOAT>(rc.right - rc.left) / font->DpiScaleX,
    static_cast<FLOAT>(rc.bottom - rc.top) / font->DpiScaleY
    );

// Use the DrawText method of the D2D render target interface to draw.

WCHAR textUnicode = Utilities::StringToWCHAR(text);
UINT32 cTextLength_ = (UINT32) wcslen(&textUnicode);

Device->D2DSolidColorBrush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(0,0,0,1));
Device->D2DSolidColorBrush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(255, 255, 255, 255));
Device->D2DRenderTarget->DrawText(&textUnicode, cTextLength_, font->DWriteTextFormat, layoutRect, Device->D2DSolidColorBrush);  
}

inline void SpriteBatch::End()
{
if (componentList_->Count)
{
    if (sortMode_ == SpriteSortMode::BackToFront)
    {
        SortByDepth();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < componentList_->Count; i++)
    {
        Texture* text = componentList_[i]->Texture->TextureInfo;
        unsigned int stride = sizeof(VertexPos);
        unsigned int offset = 0;

        Device->D3DContext->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout_);

        if (componentList_[i]->Effect != SpriteEffect::None)
        {
            ID3D11Buffer* vertexBuffer;
            float width = (float)text->textureDesc_.Width;
            float height = (float)text->textureDesc_.Height;
            D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexDesc;
            ZeroMemory(&vertexDesc, sizeof(vertexDesc));
            vertexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
            vertexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
            vertexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
            vertexDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexPos) * 6;
            D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA resourceData;
            ZeroMemory(&resourceData, sizeof(resourceData));
            pin_ptr<ID3D11Buffer*> vertexBufferPointer;
            vertexBufferPointer = &vertexBuffer;

            switch (componentList_[i]->Effect)
            {
                case BSGameFramework::Graphics::SpriteEffect::FlipHorizontally:
                {
                    VertexPos verticesOne[] =
                    {
                        { XMFLOAT3(width,  height, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                        { XMFLOAT3(width, 0.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
                        { XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) },

                        { XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) },
                        { XMFLOAT3(0.0f, height, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
                        { XMFLOAT3(width, height, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                    };

                    resourceData.pSysMem = verticesOne;

                    Device->D3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&vertexDesc, &resourceData, vertexBufferPointer);

                    Device->D3DContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

                    break;
                }

                case BSGameFramework::Graphics::SpriteEffect::FlipVertically:
                {
                    VertexPos verticesTwo[] =
                    {
                        { XMFLOAT3(width,  height, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) },
                        { XMFLOAT3(width, 0.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
                        { XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },

                        { XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                        { XMFLOAT3(0.0f, height, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
                        { XMFLOAT3(width, height, 1.0f), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) },
                    };

                    resourceData.pSysMem = verticesTwo;

                    Device->D3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&vertexDesc, &resourceData, vertexBufferPointer);

                    Device->D3DContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Device->D3DContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &text->vertexBuffer_, &stride, &offset);
        }

        Device->D3DContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

        Device->D3DContext->VSSetShader(solidColorVS_, 0, 0);
        Device->D3DContext->PSSetShader(solidColorPS_, 0, 0);
        Device->D3DContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &text->colorMap_);
        Device->D3DContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &text->colorMapSampler_);

        spriteBatch->SetTranspose(Device->D3DContext, text, Device->WindowWidth, Device->WindowHeight, componentList_[i]->Position.X, componentList_[i]->Position.Y,
            componentList_[i]->Scale.X, componentList_[i]->Scale.Y, componentList_[i]->Rotation);

        Device->D3DContext->Draw(6, 0);
    }
}

Device->D2DRenderTarget->EndDraw();
componentList_->Clear();
beginInvoked_ = false;
sortMode_ = SpriteSortMode::Deferred;
}

inline bool SpriteBatch::CompileD3DShader(char* filePath, char* entry, char* shaderModel, ID3DBlob** buffer)
{
DWORD shaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;

#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
shaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

ID3DBlob* errorBuffer = 0;
HRESULT result;

result = D3DX11CompileFromFile(filePath, 0, 0, entry, shaderModel, shaderFlags, 0, 0, buffer, &errorBuffer, 0);

if (FAILED(result))
{
    if (errorBuffer != 0)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA((char*)errorBuffer->GetBufferPointer());
        errorBuffer->Release();
    }

    return false;
}

if (errorBuffer != 0)
{
    errorBuffer->Release();
}

return true;
}

inline void SpriteBatch::SortByDepth()
{
for (int i = 0; i < componentList_->Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < componentList_->Count; j++)
    {
        if (componentList_[i]->ZIndex < componentList_[j]->ZIndex)
        {
            IDrawableComponent^ component = componentList_[i];
            componentList_[i] = componentList_[j];
            componentList_[j] = component;
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I call SpriteBatch.DrawString(...) from my C# app I'm not obtaining nothing written on my screen, can please somebody explaining me what's I'm missing? I'm new on DirectX programming so please be quiet with me xD Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of code you posted and I didn't read it all, but I was trying to do the same thing (successfully) a few days ago and I might have some suggestions.

Overall, it looks like you do this more or less the same way I do. What I did different it that I created the shared texture using `D3D11` device, but this should make no difference. The second thing, which I think could be the problem, is that you're not synchronizing the texture resource between `D3D10` and `D3D11`.

When I tried to use such resources without synchronization, `D2D` was only rendering stuff once in like 50 calls, the rest just had no effect. I think I was continously blocking the resource when rendering it with `D3D11`.

You should create the texture using

```
tDesc.MiscFlags = D3D10_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX;
```

instead. Here are the details about this flag: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172412%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Basically, you query two `IDXGIKeyedMutex` interfaces from the shared texture objects on both `D3D10` and `D3D11` devices. You lock the `D3D10` mutex when you draw your `D2D` stuff to the texture. You lock the `D3D11` mutex when you want to use this texture in `D3D11`. You do this using [IDXGIKeyedMutex::AcquireSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IDXGIKeyedMutex::ReleaseSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Just be sure to pass the same `Key` value to each consecutive `D3D10 Release -> D3D11 Acquire` and `D3D11 Release -> D3D10 Acquire` calls.

Oh, one more little, not important thing, I noticed this in your code:

```
texture->QueryInterface<IDXGISurface>(&dxgiSurface);
dxgiSurface->QueryInterface<IDXGIResource>(&dxgiResource);
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can get the `IDXGIResource` interface directly from your texture.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've solved but I've changed lot of thing but the KeyedMutex that you are suggesting is currect, thank you :D